# why the operation after for and while is not done?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I wrote this program but when I run it, nothing will happen!!
just print "odd number" or "even number"
and didn't do while and for operation

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int i, m, temp = 0;

    int a[300];

    cout << "enter a num\n";
    cin >> m;
    if (m % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "even number";

        do {
            temp = m;
            temp = temp - 2;
        } while (temp <= m);

        for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            m = a[i];
            cout << a[i];
        }
    }
    else if (m % 2 != 0) {

        cout << "Odd numbere";

        m = m - 1;

        do {
            temp = m;
            temp = temp - 2;
        }  while (temp <= m);
        for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            m = a[i];
            cout << a[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems the `do-while` operation is done and it is an infinite loop until overflow happens, so it will take long time before the `for` is executed.

Comment: Since `temp` is not used after the loop, it seems the mostly-infinite `do-while` loops should be just removed.

Comment: Also the `for` loops are bad because they are using values of uninitialized `a[i]`, which are indeterminate. Please describe your desired behavior.

Comment: Ah, in the `do-while` loop, `temp` is initialized to `m` in each iteration, so overflow won't happen and the loops are infinite unless `m` is too small.

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need the `if (m % 2 != 0)` test. If the program reaches that point, it will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Write a program that first takes a number from the input and then prints all even numbers before it >>this is the question what is your offer to fix the program?and thank you for anwser

Answer (score 1):

Look at this loop (for instance)

```
do
{
     temp = m;
     temp = temp - 2;
}
while (temp <= m);
```

Suppose when we go into this loop `m` is 10. Then we do `temp = m;` so `temp` is now 10 as well. Then we do `temp = temp - 2;` so `temp` is now 8. Then we compare `temp <= m`, since 8 is less than 10, this is true, so we go round the loop again.

Second time round the loop, we do `temp = m;`. `m` is still 10, it hasn't changed so `temp` is now 10. Then we do `temp = temp - 2;` so `temp` is now 8. Then we compare `temp <= m`, since 8 is less than 10, this is true, so we go round the loop again.

Can you see that this loop will **never** stop. You have written an infinite loop.

Now I'm not sure how to fix this, because your code is very strange. The do while loop only changes the value of `temp`, but `temp` is never used in the rest of the program, so that doesn't make sense. The for loop doesn't make any sense either. You are trying to print `a[i]` but nowhere in your code do you give `a[i]` a value. Maybe you got mixed up between `m = a[i];` and `a[i] = m;` but I'm not sure.

If you explain what the code is meant to do then maybe someone can help you fix it.

**EDIT**

So apparently this is the code you are looking for

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "enter a num\n";
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    // print all the even numbers less than m
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i += 2)
        cout << i << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

That code allows the user to enter a number, and then prints all the even numbers less than that number.

Comment: Write a program that first takes a number from the input and then prints all even numbers before it    >>this is the question

Comment: @yasi So your code is far more complicated that it needs to be to solve that problem. There's no need for arrays and no need for more than one loop to solve that problem. I'll edit the question above with some suggested code for that task.

Comment: tahnks,this is my problem in c++ that i can't write  simple code

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
     temp = m;
     temp = temp - 2;
}
while (temp <= m);
```

This is the problem. Your program will run this loop forever because `temp = m;` is a constant and it cause `while` loop keep running.

If you want to find where your code goes wrong in the future, I recommend you use a lot of `print` or `cout` in the code to find the problem.